# Vue 3 Migration - Vue-test-utils - TypeError not a Function and Mocha

Tags: vue.js, mocha.js, vuejs3, chai, vue-test-utils

I am migrating a project from vue 2 to vue 3 and working on updating the existing unit tests.  For the most part it has been smooth, but there are a few testing errors that I am having issues with.

```js
function factory (propsData) {
    let localVue = createLocalVue()
    localVue.use(Vuex)

    localVue.prototype.$context = ContextService
    localVue.prototype.$announcer = {
        announce () {},
    }

    return shallowMount(UserDetails, {
        store,
        propsData,
        localVue,
        computed: {
            fullName () {
                return 'eee'
            }
        },
        methods: {
            processTask () {
                return ''
            }
        }
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

The original factory that mount the component was as follows, for the vue 3 migration we can no longer use the createLocalVue instance, so this was removed. The global context api is now used to add the config options and load the store as a plug-in.

```js
function factory (propsData) {

return shallowMount(UserDetails, {
    props: propsData,
    global: {
        plugins: [store],
        mocks: {
            $announcer: {
                announce() {}
            }
        },
      },
    computed: {
        fullName () {
            return 'eee'
        }
    },
    methods: {
        processTask () {
            return ''
        }
    }
})
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

The following test cases, and many more similar to this will fail with the following error.  TypeError: closeAction is not a function or undefined not a function.

```js
it('should call closeDialog when closeAction() is fired', () => {
        let wrapper = factory(UserDetails, data);
      let vm = wrapper.vm
        vm.closeAction()
        expect(w.emitted().closeDialog[0], [], 'calls closeDialog when closeAction() is fired')
    })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

The wrapper vue/vm view model will only include the methods that are configured in the mount global options.  The component methods will no longer be defined, it seems they are overwritten by the config method option  However, there is some dependencies on the mock functions/methods in the options, so they are still required.

Is there anyway to still include the mock methods, but also expose the component methods to allow them to still be unit tested?

**Updated:**

When I comment out the methods config, the mounted vm on component will expose the methods again and they can be called.  However, the previous empty/mocked method is needed in the template markup below.  This will throw an error. TypeError: _ctx.processTask is not a function

```js
    <div class="row">
                <UiSetMessages scope="global" :messages="processTask()" :locale="locale" />
            </div>

  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
```

When this method call is removed, all green for the unit tests. However, this method is needed somehow.  I tried different config options to provide the method, without overwriting the component methods.

**Conclusion**

1. method config option, is deprecated in vue 3 test-utils
2. if you are migrating, existing method config will overwrite your vue wrapper model methods
3. Move you functions in the methods options, to the new stubs: options in global config.

Comment: I think you want to deep merge two objects right ? 
Also overwriting methods via the methods property is deprecated

Comment: Vue Test Utils v2 no longer supports mocking/overriding methods (via the `methods` mounting option in your case), and it would emit a warning that it has no effect. I'm also not able to reproduce the problem of your component methods being hidden. Can you share a link to a reproduction of the problem?

Comment: Here's a [demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/vue-test-mock-component-methods?file=tests/unit/UserDetails.spec.js) of your test code working (with a minor edit to the `expect` assertion, unrelated to the issue).

Comment: Thanks for looking into this.  The actual code is a trimmed down version of a very large production component.  When remove the methods: option in the existing config, the vm has the component methods again and most test pass. Great.  However the underlying error is still, there since I removed the empty method/function which is needed by the template markup. I will updated the question with the snippet